# Properties window font in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Does anyone know how to change the default font in the "Properties" window in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: You should have mentioned that you were changing it all to papyrus or comic sans to watch the typophiles cringe :)

Answer (score 4):

Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors

Answer (score 3):

From the menubar Tools>Options In the dialog Environment>Fonts and colors

Answer (score 2):

```
Tools=>Options=>Environment=>Fonts and Colors=>Font
```

[How to: Change the Font Face, Size, and Colors Used in the Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165337.aspx)